# Arch Linux 91 seconds userspace loading time

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, boot

So I am an Arch noob. It's my 10th installment in my VM and finally everything works.I did some research because my Boot was rather slow and it turns out my userspace takes 1min 30sec to load and I don't know how to fix it.

`systemd-analyze` led to the following:

```
startup finished in 1.759s (kernel) + 1min 30.212s (userspace) = 1min 31.972s

graphical.target reached after 1min 30.211s in userspace
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason of slow boot time is system wait until services loaded. 
More information you can find at [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improving_performance/Boot_process) 
To solve this issue at first you need to know which services is slowing down. 
Write:
 `systemd-analyze critical-chain`
Output of this command highlight red which services need a lot of time.
Then you need to choose:

1. Disable service, but I don't think you want disable it. In my case it was NetworkManager and docker services
2. Mask this service. This means system don't wait until it's loaded just skip it.

   I actually choose second options. Just run command:
   `sudo systemctl mask [NAME_OF_SERVICE_TO_MASK]`
   Repeat it for every service you want to mask and reboot to check is boot time reduced.
   In some cases booting time still the same, even after masking service, so, maybe your last resort is to disable service
   I hope it will help you.

Comment: Please do not deface your post. If you not longer want it to be available, then use the *delete* link on it.

Comment: I just can't find where delete it.

Comment: It should be towards the bottom-left of the answer, just above these comments, after the "share" and "edit" links.